# Music in Java (start/stop)

Tags: java, javasound, fileinputstream, audiostreamer

Ok, so I am making a game and the music changes when you are in different regions or if there is an interruption, like with an AI.

So I have JUST learned how to make music showup in my program, and now I am trying to make it stop, but I am unsure how to, below is a snippet of code where the music plays and then I try to overwite it with new music when an action occurs.

```
public static void songs(String word) {
        String temp = word;
        if (temp.equals("start")) {

            try {

                try {
                    blah = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Storage/programimages/game/battle.wav");

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                AudioStream as = new AudioStream(blah);

                AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
                System.out.println("going");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }

        if (temp.equals("stop")) {

            try {

                try {
                    blah = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Storage/programimages/game/silence.wav");

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                AudioStream as = new AudioStream(blah);

                AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
                System.out.println("stopping");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the only method I have been able to find that has the music play, but if you guys have any other suggestions please let me know.

Again, I want to have sound affects and music going, and right now all that happens is one song will play, and it will not stop under any circumstance until it hits the very end of its length. I want to be able to stop songs whenever a new one should come on, and also allow sound affects to pop up.

Thanks!
(since I am stuck on this and need an answer now I will probably repost on one or two more java sites so I can get a response ASAP, thank you though!!!!)

EDITED CODE: (still does not stop the current stream, any more suggestions appreciated)

```
public static void songs(String word) throws IOException {
    String temp = word;


    if (temp.equals("go")) {
        try {
            blah = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Storage/programimages/game/battle.wav");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        AudioStream as = new AudioStream(blah);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
        System.out.println("going");
    }

    if (temp.equals("stop")) {

        //don't try and do things with a null object!
        if (as != null) {
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
            System.out.println("stopping1");
        }
        System.out.println("stopping2");
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
    }
}
```

Comment: `AudioStream`  Which is ..what exactly?  Where are the JavaDocs for the `AudioStream` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're creating a new `AudioStream` in your stop branch and calling the stop method using this. This is a *different object* to the one that is currently playing. Try making the `AudioStream` a class variable, and calling stop on that instead.

EDIT: at the top of the class containing your code...

```
class YourClass {
    //the class member variable
    private AudioStream as;
    //[etc...]
```

In your start branch:

```
// 'as' has already been defined above
as = new AudioStream(blah);
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
System.out.println("going");
```

In your stop branch:

```
try
{
    //don't try and do things with a null object!
    if (as != null)
    {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
    }
    System.out.println("stopping");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

You may have trouble with the `static` identifier on your method - if you're calling this from within an instantiated class you don't need this.

Comment: well, I am trying that now but I am getting a lot of errors, too many to really explain and make it useful at all. Can you give me a basic layout of where you want to try and implement the variable of audiostream and where to start stop it at? And I am better off "stopping" it, or just playing some "silent" track instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Austin: hopefully my edit will help. wds: The stop being called is on AudioPlayer.player. If he was trying to call a method that didn't exist, the code wouldn't even compile. Just trying to be helpful with the information we have.

Comment: Ok, here is what I have now... Still doesn't work btw.

Now, when I hit the stop button or leave or anything changes it prints out "stopping2" meaning, as is not null. 
The orignal music still plays and it does not hault. I tried swapping out stop with playing a silent music file and all it does is run on top of the other sound. I need to somehow CUT the stream. 
I EDITED my post with the new code

Comment: @raveturned I also just noticed this...

warning: sun.audio.(insert each item below here) is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release:

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
private static AudioStream as;
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(blah);
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(blah);
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);

Comment: In your "go" branch, change `AudioStream as = new AudioStream(blah);` to just `as = new AudioStream(blah);`, as per my example.

Comment: Also, the API for sun.audio classes can be found [here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/audio/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't even access these sun.audio Objects on my Eclipse IDE--I know they are in rt.jar, but there is header info about them being proprietary and such.

Can the Java Sound library (javax.sound.sampled) handle what you want to do? Both Clip and SourceDataLine allow one to stop playback. That is a more usual way of playing sound, if you want to use native Java.

Playback into is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

But the documentation, overall, is not exactly rich with examples. There's example code at this site

http://www.jsresources.org/

and plenty of people here who could help if you run into problems with the native Java approach.